# PHP : Parsing the JSON "PUT" data giving EMPTY Array?

Tags: php, json, api, curl, put

I'm making a small API in PHP. And I'm having some problem with `PUT` verb. Here are my test scripts for `PUT`.

(Submitter) submit.php:

```
$data = array("fruit"=>"watermelon", "destination"=>"germany");
$data = json_encode($data);

// echo json_last_error(); //Returns: 0 (JSON Data Integrity Check. So I supposed there is NO ERROR in JSON Object)

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/api.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$respond = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($respond);
```

(Receiver) api.php:

```
$decoded_input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
parse_str($decoded_input, $putdata);
echo json_encode( $putdata );
```

### Output

```
[]
```

### But.. wait!

But.... when I DON'T use JSON data-type in the submission (Comment out below 2 lines):

```
//$data = json_encode($data);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)));
```

Then I got something returned like:

```
stdClass Object ( [------------------------------4f5f68d9cc92 Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "fruit" watermalon ------------------------------4f5f68d9cc92 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="origin" germany ------------------------------4f5f68d9cc92-- )
```

- What is happening when I use the `JSON` data-type in the Submission please?
- More importantly, how to submit and parse the JSON DATA through PUT method?

Comment: You should *not* edit your question to implement solutions proposed. It makes the solutions invalid.  Editing your question should be to add clarification or improve formatting.

Comment: Hi @BeetleJuice i just edited it to be more informative. But i didn't change anything major upon the original description. Thanks much for your helps mate. :))

Comment: does your webserver accept json data type?

Comment: Hi @vitr, yes definitely (as it is indeed the production Apache with many other PHP sites there.) And, when i test with the POST method, the JSON everything all working fine. (Just the PUT method is having problem in parsing)

Comment: you must remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` then

Comment: Hi @vitr, i tried removing that, and still gives me the blank.

Comment: man, just do 1 step at a time, echo file_get_contents("php://input") and you will get the idea...

Comment: I tried as you suggest. But as long as i use JSON as data-type, i get blank. And as soon as i don't use JSON type, i get data. So confusing. :(

Comment: your server doesn't accept json in PUT, period, perhaps, it doesn't accept PUT at all, use tools like postman to test your server

Comment: Hi @vitr, thanks for the suggestion. Is there such a thing where a server doesn't accept json in PUT? I just tried using Postman; and it's still the same result. (With JSON it is blank output. Without JSON it receives the data) Thanks again.

Comment: your production server just isn't configured to accept something more than post and get, you need to see the configs, logs, etc. I would suggest you to run your script in a trusted environment (say apache+php docker image), get the php right, then return to the production server and find out what is configured differently. and delete this question, as you may get more downvotes, and delete the other one you created, it's a server configuration question. you'll be downvoted because of that

Comment: (If you want to enquire about downvotes, feel free to do so in comments. However it is not of interest to most readers, so we'd appreciate it if it could be kept out of post bodies, thanks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You set data to a JSON string

```
$data = json_encode($data);
```

Then try to retrieve it using `parse_str`

```
parse_str( file_get_contents("php://input"), $putdata);
```

`parse_str` cannot parse JSON. You need `json_decode`:

```
// will be NULL if the decode fails
$putdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
if(is_null($putdata)) die(json_last_error());
```

I also notice some problems with your `CURL` options. Specifically, you mix `POST` and `PUT` settings. Remove this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Comment: Hi @BeetleJuice, thanks much for helps. But i'm now getting `null` instead.

Comment: `json_decode` returns `NULL` when the decode fail. This can happen if you have non UTF-8 characters in your JSON or if your data is too complex.  what do you see if you execute the last line in my updated answer?

Comment: I just edited my code according to your last edit. But it shows BLANK return now. (No errors there). Also i exactly used the Array `$data = array("fruit"=>"watermelon", "destination"=>"germany");` as in JSON, which is pure UTF-8 characters obviously. I don't think it is encoding issue. Any kind suggestions please?

Comment: I would expect my code to show blank because I didn't echo anything to the screen (except errors).  what shows if you `print_r($putdata)` after the `json_decode`

Comment: Hi @BeetleJuice, `print_r($putdata)` also returns blank. (And i also did that `json_last_error()` checking even in the submission code. And it returns `0` which means no error in Json.)

Comment: Then perhaps **api.php** never even gets the data. do you see anything if you `echo file_get_contents("php://input")`? If there's nothing there, your problem has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, if i turn off (don't use) `json` data-type in the submission file, then the `api.php` file returns data. Which means the data is there.

Comment: so what do you see when you send JSON and you `echo file_get_contents("php://input")` from `api.php`

Comment: Hi, that also returns blank. :(

Comment: Ok, that's a separate issue from the JSON question you ask here. I suggest you open a new question with the code for making a request from `submit.php` to `api.php` and ask how come when you send data, `php://input` is blank.

Comment: Ok thanks much for suggestion, but... isn't my current question still the same meaning with what you suggest to ask as new? I already mentioned here, that, when i submit `json` it becomes blank. I don't know how to ask as new one. :(

Comment: Your question here is that "Parsing JSON PUT data gives empty array" and all the discussion has been about how to properly parse JSON data.  I believe the real issue is that you are unable to send data to `api.php` period.  That's why `php://input` is blank.  The problem is likely with your `CURL` options. Anyway you won't get the people you need to see this question because the title seems to suggest that the problem is about parsing JSON.

Comment: I got your point. But why i get data (everything) when i use POST, GET methods instead of PUT (in the same file)? So I'm enable to send JSON data to `api.php` file, but just only the PUT method is having issues. And that's what i ask helps for.

Comment: I've added a bit to the end of my solution. Does that work?

Comment: Hi @BeetleJuice it's still the same. I start thinking the "submitting JSON via PUT" is a difficulty. I started new question as you suggested. Please kindly help there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451617/php-how-to-submit-json-via-the-put-method