# PHP : How to submit "JSON" via the PUT method?

Tags: php, json, apache, http-headers, put

I'm making (and testing) my small PHP API. Both GET/POST methods are all fine while submitting the `JSON` as data-type.

### Problem in PUT

- I cannot submit the `JSON` data via `PUT` method. When i do, the Server-side got empty data.
- **But when i DO NOT use `json` as data-type, (and just use the plain text data), then i can receive and parse the data, successfully**. <----(( This is something weird! ))

Here are my tested cases.

### Client Side (Submissions)

(Submit via PHP) submit.php:

```
$data = array("fruit"=>"watermelon", "destination"=>"germany");
$data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/api.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$respond = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($respond);
```

(Submit via Postman):

[image]

### Server Side (Receiving / Parsing)

api.php:

```
$decoded_input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
parse_str($decoded_input, $putdata);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $putdata );
```

### Output

```
[]
```

### Question

So it seems like receiving/parsing at the **Server-side is the issue**.

- How to submit JSON data-type via the PUT method?
- Are there some settings in my Server Side (`Apache + PHP`) to enable (to allow) the `json` data-type in `PUT` method?

** I just can't get JSON works via the PUT method. Thanks all for kind helps.

Comment: can you have receive "decoded_input" value?

Comment: Hi @HariKrishnan.P, `decoded_input` is blank. Any advise please? (I also edited (improved) the question a bit). Thanks :))

Comment: what is the client side response "print_r($respond);" can you print the "data" array value before CURL init()

Comment: Why do you use `parse_str()` in `api.php`? In your case it's applied to an array. Just remove this line. After `json_decode` you should have php array.

Comment: Hi @Wazelin, when i tried as u suggest, then i got `null`. (I just can't submit JSON via PUT. I tried with many submission tools already) :(

Comment: Well.. Did you change the last line to `echo json_encode( $decoded_input );`?

Comment: You should definitely enable error reporting on your development environment. It seems you skip all the errors.

Comment: Hi @HariKrishnan.P, for the one you asked, it is: `{"fruit":"watermelon","destination":"germany"}`

Comment: Just check any error in the code which using this "echo ini_get('display_errors');

if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

echo ini_get('display_errors');"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$decoded_input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

//Here you have usual php array stored in $decoded_input. Do some stuff with it.

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($decoded_input);
```

[image]

Comment: I used it exactly like yours, but getting the Empty (or) Blank data. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment, Rep to low.

Some weeks ago i also played around with simple API calls and i made a little function to handle them.

```
public function callAPI($method, $url, $data = false) {

    $ch = curl_init ();

    switch ($method) {
        case "POST" :
            curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

            if ($data) {
                curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
                curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Content-Length: ' . strlen ( $data ) 
                ));
            }
            break;
        case "PUT" :
            curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1 );
            break;
        case "GET" :
            //No settings required
        break;
    }

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

    $responde = curl_exec ( $ch );

    curl_close ( $ch );

    return $responde;
}
```

Seems like there is another setting required for `PUT`

`curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1 );`

AFAIK your option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");` only changes the string which is sent, not the actual method

Soruce: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.html